# unable to set/get the property values in the rowMapper

Tags: spring-batch

I'm trying to access the StepExecution in my RowMapper but unable to do so. I have a property set in the xml called 'prop1'. I expect this to be set but it is not setting.I also added a @BeforeStep method to the RowMapper hoping I can get the stepExecutionContext but this method is never invoked. Is there something else I need to do?

Here is my xml:

```
<bean id="bean1"
class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader"
scope="step">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<property name="sql"
    value="${sql}"/>
<property name="fetchSize" value="${fetchSize}"></property>
<property name="rowMapper">
    <bean id="rowMapper1" class="c.p.MyRowMapper" scope="step">
        <property name="prop1" value="${prop1}"></property>
</property>
```

Here is my RowMapper:

```
public class MyRowMapper implements RowMapper<Object>{

  private String prop1;
  private StepExecution se;
  public String getProp1() {
      return stepFatpCount;
  }
  public void setProp1(String rop1) {
      this. prop1 = prop1;
  }

  @BeforeStep
  public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution){

    this.se = stepExecution;

  }
}
```

I have some properties set in the stepExecutionContext before this step in another step and I want to use them here in the RowMapper. The same thing works in the ItemProcessor but not the RowMapper. Please let me know if I need to do something more for lazy binding or any other issue. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The step execution context is not shared between steps. Maybe you mean job execution context?

I suppose you could register `rowMapper1` as a listener in the step (with the `<listeners>` tag), but if you just want to read some value from the job execution context you could use

```
value="#{jobExecutionContext['foobar']}"
```

If you do want to have injected some value from the step execution context, you just have to replace `stepExecutionContext` above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I meant JobExecutionContext and not the step but, I want to access the jobExecutionContext from the stepExecution in the RowMapper.

Comment: But how do I access the prop1 in the RowMapper? I have the setter/getter in place but I don't see the value being set. Any help?

Comment: So the property prop1 value is actually setting. That's good. But I'm still not able to access the stepExecutionContext or the jobExecutionContext in the rowMapper